# Cannot create container from docker-compose due to short volume name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose up` with this docker-compose.yml.

```
version: '3'

services:
    rundeck:
        build:
            context: ./
            args:
                RUNDECK_IMAGE: ${RUNDECK_IMAGE:-rundeck/rundeck:SNAPSHOT}
        links:
          - mysql
        tty: true
        environment:
            RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL: http://localhost
            RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED: 'true'
            RUNDECK_DATABASE_DRIVER: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            RUNDECK_DATABASE_USERNAME: rundeck
            RUNDECK_DATABASE_PASSWORD: rundeck
            RUNDECK_DATABASE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
            RUNDECK_PLUGIN_EXECUTIONFILESTORAGE_NAME: com.rundeck.rundeckpro.amazon-s3
            RUNDECK_PLUGIN_EXECUTIONFILESTORAGE_S3_BUCKET: ${RUNDECK_PLUGIN_EXECUTIONFILESTORAGE_S3_BUCKET}
            RUNDECK_PLUGIN_EXECUTIONFILESTORAGE_S3_REGION: ${RUNDECK_PLUGIN_EXECUTIONFILESTORAGE_S3_REGION}
            RUNDECK_STORAGE_CONVERTER_1_CONFIG_PASSWORD: ${RUNDECK_STORAGE_PASSWORD}
            RUNDECK_CONFIG_STORAGE_CONVERTER_1_CONFIG_PASSWORD: ${RUNDECK_STORAGE_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
          - data:/home/rundeck/server/data
          - ${AWS_CREDENTIALS}:/home/rundeck/.aws/credentials
          - ${RUNDECK_LICENSE_FILE:-/dev/null}:/home/rundeck/etc/rundeckpro-license.key
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        links:
          - rundeck
        volumes:
          - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
        ports:
          - 80:80
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        expose:
          - 3306
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=rundeck
          - MYSQL_USER=rundeck
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=rundeck
        volumes:
          - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    data:
    dbdata:
```

I get the following error:

```
xxxx_mysql_1 is up-to-date
Creating xxxx_rundeck_1 ... error

ERROR: for xxxx_rundeck_1  Cannot create container for service rundeck: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters

ERROR: for rundeck  Cannot create container for service rundeck: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I don't see a `create .` statement anywhere in the docker-compose.yml or the Dockerfile.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you include a minimal subset of the `docker-compose.yml` file, enough to reproduce this error message, as text, in the question (not behind a link)?

Comment: Maybe the `AWS_CREDENTIALS` is empty? Can you try without this volume?

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was? I'm running into the same error message...

Comment: I had this issue because I was running `docker-compose up` in the wrong directory locally and the config file was not being picked up. If you run into this issue try double checking the directory is correct if you have directory specific config.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the variable in env file. It is commented and hence adds null value to config.
https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/blob/master/cloud/.env.dist#L3

Used in

https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/blob/master/cloud/docker-compose.yml#L27

I got same issue and it resolved once i updated the env variables with value.

Answer (score 0):

I once got this issue when the `.env` file contained

```
AWS_CREDENTIALS:foo
```

instead of

```
AWS_CREDENTIALS=foo
```